# Getting trouble in loading fine-tuned model to call predict

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I'm new to tensorflow and BERT, n I followed some tutorials on webs to fine-tuning DistilBert by my own dataset on here,
https://medium.com/geekculture/hugging-face-distilbert-tensorflow-for-custom-text-classification-1ad4a49e26a7

My dataset consists of only two column, "message" and "label", looks like,
[pic1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hA5ps.png)

I trained model successfully, and predict.proba function also worked well.
but when i saved model, i get some warnings like

```
WARNING:tensorflow:Skipping full serialization of Keras layer <keras.layers.core.dropout.Dropout object at 0x000001B910694D88>, because it is not built.
WARNING:tensorflow:Skipping full serialization of Keras layer <keras.layers.core.dropout.Dropout object at 0x000001B97BBC58C8>, because it is not built.
WARNING:tensorflow:Skipping full serialization of Keras layer <keras.layers.core.dropout.Dropout object at 0x000001B97BCF0E48>, because it is not built.
WARNING:tensorflow:Skipping full serialization of Keras layer <keras.layers.core.dropout.Dropout object at 0x000001B91071AB08>, because it is not built.
WARNING:tensorflow:Skipping full serialization of Keras layer <keras.layers.core.dropout.Dropout object at 0x000001B91072E388>, because it is not built.
WARNING:tensorflow:Skipping full serialization of Keras layer <keras.layers.core.dropout.Dropout object at 0x000001B91073FC48>, because it is not built.
WARNING:absl:Found untraced functions such as embeddings_layer_call_fn, embeddings_layer_call_and_return_conditional_losses, transformer_layer_call_fn, transformer_layer_call_and_return_conditional_losses, LayerNorm_layer_call_fn while saving (showing 5 of 164). These functions will not be directly callable after loading.
```

and when i load saved model and call predict function again, i get error.
i used keras.models.load_model(), tf.saved_model.load() and tf.keras.models.load_model but still getting error like,

```
ValueError: Exception encountered when calling layer "tf_distil_bert_for_sequence_classification" (type TFDistilBertForSequenceClassification).
Could not find matching concrete function to call loaded from the SavedModel.Got:
  Positional arguments (9 total):
    * {'input_ids': <tf.Tensor 'input_ids_1:0' shape=(None, 100) dtype=int32>, 'attention_mask': <tf.Tensor 'input_ids:0' shape=(None, 100) dtype=int32>}
    * None
    * None
    * None
    * None
    * None
    * None
    * None
    * False
  Keyword arguments: {}

 Expected these arguments to match one of the following 2 option(s):

Option 1:
  Positional arguments (9 total):
    * {'input_ids': TensorSpec(shape=(None, 5), dtype=tf.int32, name='input_ids/input_ids')}
    * None
    * None
    * None
    * None
    * None
    * None
    * None
    * False
  Keyword arguments: {}

Option 2:
  Positional arguments (9 total):
    * {'input_ids': TensorSpec(shape=(None, 5), dtype=tf.int32, name='input_ids/input_ids')}
    * None
    * None
    * None
    * None
    * None
    * None
    * None
    * True
  Keyword arguments: {}

Call arguments received:
  • args=({'input_ids': 'tf.Tensor(shape=(None, 100), dtype=int32)', 'attention_mask': 'tf.Tensor(shape=(None, 100), dtype=int32)'},)
  • kwargs={'training': 'False'}
```

I'm confused why saved model doesn't work same as before. Can i get any advice?

Here's my full code:

```
import pandas as pd
import tensorflow as tf
import tensorflow_hub as hub
import transformers
from transformers import DistilBertTokenizer
from transformers import TFDistilBertForSequenceClassification
from transformers import TFTrainer, TFTrainingArguments

pd.set_option('display.max_colwidth', None)
BATCH_SIZE = 16
N_EPOCHS = 3

df = pd.read_csv('twitter.csv', names=["message", "label"], encoding='cp949')

X = list(df['message'])
y = list(df['label'])
y = list(pd.get_dummies(y,drop_first=True)[True])

from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size = 0.20, random_state = 0)

tokenizer = DistilBertTokenizer.from_pretrained('distilbert-base-uncased')

train_encodings = tokenizer(X_train, truncation=True, padding=True)
test_encodings = tokenizer(X_test, truncation=True, padding=True)

train_dataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices((
    dict(train_encodings),
    y_train
))

test_dataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices((
    dict(test_encodings),
    y_test
))

model = TFDistilBertForSequenceClassification.from_pretrained("distilbert-base-uncased")

#chose the optimizer
optimizerr = tf.keras.optimizers.Adam(learning_rate=5e-5)

#define the loss function 
losss = tf.keras.losses.SparseCategoricalCrossentropy(from_logits=True)

#build the model
model.compile(optimizer=optimizerr,
              loss=losss,
              metrics=['accuracy'])

history = model.fit(train_dataset.shuffle(len(X_train)).batch(BATCH_SIZE),
          epochs=N_EPOCHS,
          batch_size=BATCH_SIZE)

# model evaluation on the test set
model.evaluate(test_dataset.shuffle(len(X_test)).batch(BATCH_SIZE), 
               return_dict=True, 
               batch_size=BATCH_SIZE)

# tests
def predict_proba(text_list, model, tokenizer):  
    #tokenize the text
    encodings = tokenizer(text_list, 
                          max_length=1000, 
                          truncation=True, 
                          padding=True)
    #transform to tf.Dataset
    dataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices((dict(encodings)))
    #predict
    preds = model.predict(dataset.batch(1)).logits  
    
    #transform to array with probabilities
    res = tf.nn.softmax(preds, axis=1).numpy()      
    
    return res

examples = [
    'In 2008, several failing banks were bailed out partially using taxpayer money. Putting all money at bank provide risk, risk of devaluation, risk of inflation, risk of aggressive centralise policy. Decentralized system like bitcoin working on blockchain provide relief.',
    'Bitcoin is counterfeit. Disagree? Look again.',
    'Did I make a bad GPU purchase before the end of Ethereum mining?',
    '@Mamooetz Help. I created this bot to reply to ETH, BITCOIN, and NFT but I dont know how to shut it off.',
    '@WaldorickWilson Cryptocurrency doesnt have to be cryptic. Luno takes the complexity out of #Bitcoin and lets you buy, store, learn and earn all in one place',
]

result = predict_proba(examples, model, tokenizer)
print(result)

# save model
dataset_name = 'adv'
saved_model_path = './{}_bert'.format(dataset_name.replace('/', '_'))

# model.save(saved_model_path)
tf.saved_model.save(model, saved_model_path)

# load model
loaded_model = tf.saved_model.load(saved_model_path)
inference_function = loaded_model.signatures['serving_default']

reloaded = tf.keras.models.load_model(saved_model_path)
predict_proba(examples, reloaded, tokenizer)
```

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).